# how to delete a row from a table in android ?

Tags: android, database

This is the delete method m using in Handler class:

```
    public void deleteRow(long rowId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
  }
```

1. I want to delete the selected row from the list view. Here is my code for ListView, which is not showing any error in the logcat, but not deleting the row.! what might be the problem?:

   ```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               final int position, long id) {
           TextView textView = (TextView) view
                   .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
           String s = textView.getText().toString();


           AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                   context);
           alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete?");
           alertDialogBuilder
                   .setMessage("Click yes to delete")
                   .setCancelable(false)

                   .setNegativeButton("No",
                           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                       int which) {
                                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                   dialog.cancel();// close the dialog and
                                                   // do nothing..
                               }
                           })
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                       int which) {


                                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                   db = new SQLiteHandler(context);
                                   db.open();
                                   db.deleteRow(position);
                                   db.close();

                               }
                           });

           // create alert dialog
           AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

           // show it
           alertDialog.show();
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: replace KEY_ID to "_id" n try..

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this:

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "= ?"  , new String[] { ""+rowId });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..I got the solution.. Actually i need to pass the 'id' but i was passing 'position' in listView..It is working fine now.. Thank u all..

Answer (score 0):

```
db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(rowId)});
```